# Validation not possible

Tags: css, validation, web

I wanted to validate my Website for example with http://validator.w3.org but I always get the following error:

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 11 it
>   contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other
>   words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character
>   Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character
>   encoding indication. The error was: utf8 "\xFC" does not map to
>   Unicode

Does anybody know where I can locate/get rid of the error?

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste the code into the validation? Or are you able to provide a link to your site/code?

Comment: Yes, but I tested my Site on seitenreport.de and they found 56 errors in the CSS. Now I want to locate these errors. My Problem: I am using Wordpress and there are thousands of CSS files. The Validation will show me, where the files are located and in which line the problem is.

Comment: \xFC is ü, does this appear in your line 11?

Comment: Try this it seems to be the same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302897/html-xhtml-validation-error-cant-resolve

Comment: It will be which ever file you are trying to validate so for example yoursite.com/index.php The issue will properly be caused by you copying and pasting from another source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the css-file with your favorite text editor. 
There, switch the encoding to UTF8.
Goto line 11 and look for strange looking symbols.
Delete/replace them.

Comment: There are no strange looking symbols.

Comment: Can you link us to your page so we can look or copy lines 5 - 15 to give use a better chance of helping?

Comment: I took the index.php and the style.css file and switched the encoding to UTF-8 and saved it. But it's not working anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change it into UTF-8 without BOM